# Reply on same network interface (UDP)

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, udp, raspbian

is it possible to reply all incoming packets/request on same network interface?

This is my setting: I have a headless Raspberry Pi (raspbian) with two network interfaces (eth0 and eth1). The fist interface (eth0) uses a public IP address, which is static. This interface is intended to provide access to the Pi (time- and web server, SSH) via the Internet. The second interface (eth1) uses the Raspberry Pi for general Internet connection (perform updates, sync own time or whatever) and uses a dynamic IP via DHCP. A general Internet connectivity over eth0 is not possible, so I have to use eth1 on the Pi.

My problem is that Internet (on the Pi) and the Internet access to the Pi are not working correctly.

first configuration (/etc/dhcpcd.conf):

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=141.41.241.68/28
static routers=141.41.241.65 192.168.0.1
```

after reboot 'ifconfig' shows the correct IP settings:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 141.41.241.68  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 141.41.241.79
        ...

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ...
```

result:

- Internet on the Raspberry Pi (eth1): **doesn't work**
- access to Raspberry Pi over Internet (via eth0):

  - SSH (TCP): **works fine**
  - Apache web server (TCP): **works fine**
  - NTP time server (UDP): **works fine**

---

Now I tried to change the metric of the interfaces, hoping that the change of prioritization is successful

second configuration (/etc/dhcpcd.conf):

```
interface eth1
metric 200

interface eth0
static ip_address=141.41.241.68/28
static routers=141.41.241.65 192.168.0.1
metric 201
```

result:

- Internet on the Raspberry Pi (eth1): **works fine**
- access to Raspberry Pi over Internet (via eth0):

  - SSH (TCP): **doesn't work**
  - Apache web server (TCP): **doesn't work**
  - NTP time server (UDP): **doesn't work**

Ok. I think all traffic going out to eth1 at default. With the tool 'iptraf-ng' I was able to see the problem:

```
TCP Connections (Source Host:Port)  Iface
--------------------------------------------------
80.187.108.126:53024                eth0 
141.41.241.68:80                    eth0 
141.41.241.68:80                    eth1 
80.187.108.126:53024                eth1 
80.187.108.126:53025                eth0 
141.41.241.68:80                    eth0 
141.41.241.68:80                    eth1 
80.187.108.126:53025                eth1 

UDP Connections
--------------------------------------------------
UDP (76 bytes) from 80.187.108.126:28599 to 141.41.241.68:123 on eth0
UDP (76 bytes) from 192.168.0.101:123 to 80.187.108.126:28599 on eth1
```

We see:

On TCP: some connections going out to the wrong interface (eth1).

On UDP: The request from 80.187.108.126 came over eth0 and the response was sent over eth1.

---

Next, I defined the routing table to reply incoming packets on same network interface...

```
echo 100 public >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add from 141.41.241.68/32 table public
ip route add default via 141.41.241.65 dev eth0 table public
```

result:

- Internet on the Raspberry Pi (eth1): **works fine**
- access to Raspberry Pi over Internet (via eth0):

  - SSH (TCP): **works fine**
  - Apache web server (TCP): **works fine**
  - NTP time server (UDP): **doesn't work**

and 'iptraf-ng' shows:

```
TCP Connections (Source Host:Port)  Iface
--------------------------------------------------
141.41.241.68:80                    eth0
80.187.108.126:52083                eth0
141.41.241.68:80                    eth0
80.187.108.126:52084                eth0
141.41.241.68:80                    eth0
80.187.108.126:52085                eth0
141.41.241.68:80                    eth0
80.187.108.126:52086                eth0
141.41.241.68:80                    eth0
80.187.108.126:52087                eth0

UDP Connections
--------------------------------------------------
UDP (76 bytes) from 80.187.108.126:28599 to 141.41.241.68:123 on eth0
UDP (76 bytes) from 192.168.0.101:123 to 80.187.108.126:28599 on eth1
```

We see:

On TCP: now it works correctly

On UDP: same problem :(

What can I do to send UDP responses over the correct interface (eth0)? I have no idea why TCP works fine but UDP fails :(
Its very frustrating and I have no more ideas. 
I hope someone can help.

best regards,
SBond

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for network configuration help, 
tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry. Thanks for the information. I keep it in my mind